# set up eclipse CDT but having this weird error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am following these steps (https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) to set up the CDT environment. I followed every step, and I have a simple hello-world program. However when I build, I am having following error.

```
04:04:24 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project WebServer 

****
make all 
Building file: ../src/WebServer.cpp
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -I"C:\Cygwin32\bin\" -I"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.9.2\include\c++" -I"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.9.2\include\c++\i686-pc-cygwin" -I"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.9.2\include\c++\backward" -I"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.9.2\include" -I"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.9.2\include-fixed" -I"C:\cygwin64\usr\include" -I"C:\cygwin64\usr\include\w32api" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/WebServer.d" -MT"src/WebServer.d" -o "src/WebServer.o" "../src/WebServer.cpp"
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/WebServer.o' failed
make: *** [src/WebServer.o] Error 1

04:04:25 Build Finished (took 204ms)
```

I did quite a few searches online but they all seem unrelated. I really don't know what I did wrong. The program itself is a simple helloworld and should have no problem.

Comment: Looks like your missing a closing double quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you have the made the setting `"C:\Cygwin32\bin\"`, change it to `"C:\\Cygwin32\\bin"`(and similarly in other Windows-style pathnames). The unescaped trailing `\` is causing the following `"` to be escaped and ignored, resulting in unbalanced quotes. Better still, use the unix directory separator `/` rather than Windows `\`, as the latter escapes the following the character in unix shells.

Answer (score 0):

What does your /bin/sh point to? This seems like a typical "wrong shell" error. Try to change the sh pointer to something else. F.ex. in Ubuntu dash is what sh points to, but many scripts aren't compatible with it.

So setting sh to point to bash usually solves the problem.

Editing the shell in cygwin can be done in /etc/passwd, as described here: https://m.reddit.com/r/cygwin/comments/2s9v8y/changing_cygwins_default_shell/

Comment: Hello. I honestly don't know what this /bin/sh is and not sure I set it anywhere. I followed the tutorial closely and don't remember ever playing with it.

Comment: @bookmonkie, you seem to be on Windows in a Cygwin environment, there you can set your user's shell in   /etc/passwd - see here:  https://m.reddit.com/r/cygwin/comments/2s9v8y/changing_cygwins_default_shell/